# Styling a QPushButton with two images

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I used `QSS` to style a `QPushButton`. I wanted to use two images to be set as the background-image. One for normal state & one when the button is pressed. But image shows with a border around it.

My code:

```
QPushButton{
background-image: url();
border-image: url(images/back/up.png);
color:rgb(255,255,255);
border-width: 2px;
border-radius:  22px;
}
QPushButton::pressed {
border-image:url(images/back/up1.png);
border-width: 2px;
background-image: url();
color:rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is burr? Do you mean blur? Can you show both cases (what you expect and what you actually see)?

Comment: Fist,Thank you for your time to answer my question,My English is not good,burr means the border of icon(actually see)  is not neat like the pic!I want use css change the shape of Qt creator‘s QPushButton！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following style snippet. You only need to change the `background-image` during the `:pressed` state.

```
QPushButton{
background-image: url(images/back/up.png);
color:rgb(255,255,255);
border-width: 2px;
border-radius: 22px;
}

QPushButton::pressed {
background-image:url(images/back/up1.png);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I had solution my question by your another answer of other's question!